# Splitting the string with the file extension in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the last number from the filename for which I used `strsplit` in R but the splitted value is getting attached with the file extension which I want to get rid of, here is what I have tried

```
fnames <- basename("D:/Processed files/ABC_4.csv")
strsplit(fnames,"_")
```

**Output**

```
"ABC" "4.csv"
```

alternatively I tried doing  `strsplit(fnames,"_ .")` also

Any help would be much appreciated,Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `gsub`

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", fnames))
#[1] 4
```

Or

```
as.numeric(gsub("^.*_|[^0-9]+$", "", fnames))
```

Or with `stri_extract_last`

```
library(stringi)
as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(fnames, "\\d+"))
#[1] 4
```